# Create index for tables within Delta Lake

Tags: apache-spark, indexing, delta-lake

I'm new to the Delta Lake, but I want to create some indexes for fast retrieval for some tables in Delta Lake. Based on the docs, it shows that the closest is by creating the Data Skipping then indexing the skipped portion:

```
create DATASKIPPING index on [TableName] [DBName.]tableName
```

Can't seem to find other methods of creating indexes other than Data Skipping

How do I create indexes just like any tables in RDBMS, within Delta Lake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Indexing happens [automatically on Databricks Delta](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#data-skipping) and [OSS Delta Lake as of v1.2.0](https://docs.delta.io/latest/optimizations-oss.html#data-skipping). As you write data, the columns in the files you write are indexed and added to the internal table metadata. As you query the data and filter, data skipping is applied.

In addition you can use [z-order](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#z-ordering-multi-dimensional-clustering) on Databricks Delta to optimize the files based on specific columns. Again, indexing will still be used for the other columns as well.

Comment: The opensource version does not seem to implement this feature :(

Comment: Add comment to clarify OSS is working on it

Comment: Now included with OSS Delta Lake as well