# How to make same pattern multiple joins in Trino SQL shorter?

Tags: sql, trino

## Background

I have a Delta table `motor` which has too many columns.

Due to [AWS Glue Catalog schema size 400KB limit](https://repost.aws/questions/QUvbjcqsavTF633n47J02MMw/feature-request-increase-aws-glue-catelog-400-kb-schema-size-limit), I have to split the table.

To simplify the question, for example, before I have columns `timestamp`, `col0`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, ... , `col79`.

After splitting to 8 tables, I have tables

- motor_0: `timestamp`, `col0`, `col1`, ..., `col9`
- motor_1: `timestamp`, `col10`, `col11`, ..., `col19`
- ...
- motor_7: `timestamp`, `col70`, `col71`, ..., `col79`

Note the same `timestamp` column is reserved across all tables.

## Question

Now, I am using Trino SQL to join these tables. Here is my current SQL:

```
with t0 as (
    select * from delta.my_delta_db.motor_0
    order by timestamp desc limit 1000
),
t1 as (
    select * from delta.my_delta_db.motor_1
    order by timestamp desc limit 1000
),
t2 as (
    select * from delta.my_delta_db.motor_2
    order by timestamp desc limit 1000
),
t3 as (
    select * from delta.my_delta_db.motor_3
    order by timestamp desc limit 1000
),
t4 as (
    select * from delta.my_delta_db.motor_4
    order by timestamp desc limit 1000
),
t5 as (
    select * from delta.my_delta_db.motor_5
    order by timestamp desc limit 1000
),
t6 as (
    select * from delta.my_delta_db.motor_6
    order by timestamp desc limit 1000
),
t7 as (
    select * from delta.my_delta_db.motor_7
    order by timestamp desc limit 1000
),
select * from t0
     join t1 on t0.timestamp = t1.timestamp
     join t2 on t0.timestamp = t2.timestamp
     join t3 on t0.timestamp = t3.timestamp
     join t4 on t0.timestamp = t4.timestamp
     join t5 on t0.timestamp = t5.timestamp
     join t6 on t0.timestamp = t6.timestamp
     join t7 on t0.timestamp = t7.timestamp
order by t0.timestamp desc limit 1000
```

The reason I am adding `order by timestamp desc limit 1000` in each `with` block is to make each Trino sub-task output data size small. This helps avoid joining the total number of rows for each join.

I am wondering if there is a way to make this query shorter but also not lose performance?

I found Trino has a [WITH RECURSIVE](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#with-recursive-clause), but seems not applying to my case (?)

Any guide would be appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to deal with a poor or possibly denormalised design, have you created them with a clustered index on the timestamp column? What do you mean by "make the query shorter" ? Less text? The written size of a query has no correlation with its performance once compiled.

Comment: Thanks @Stu for reminding! There would be [z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58585002/2000548) on `timestamp` column in this Delta table. Yeah, just hopefully less text so that I don’t have to repeat same text. But if can further improve performance in another SQL, that will be even better! 

Comment: I'm not familiar with `trino` so can't suggest and product specific tuning, however if you can use temporary tables perhaps insert your 1000 rows from `t0` and then join with the temp table? Normally with a clustered index seek you won't need to use CTEs like this just join the tables.